# C++ return vector, can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: c++, memory-management

The following program keeps crashing and I can't figure out what's wrong. It seems that v is somehow not available in the main function..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> *asdf()
{
    vector<string> *v = new vector<string>();
    v->push_back("blah");
    v->push_back("asdf");
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> *v = NULL;
    v = asdf();

    for (int i=0; i<(v->size()); v++) {
        cout << (*v)[i] << endl;
    }

    delete v;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lol dumbest bug ever I guess, thx for the help!

Comment: You should get rid of the dynamic allocation in this code, there's no reason for it.

Comment: Well it was just a stupid example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want:

```
 for (int i=0; i<(v->size()); i++) {
```

Your code is incrementing the pointer, not the index. which is a good reason to avoid dynamically allocating things, wherever possible.

Comment: Using an iterator is even preferable IHMO

Comment: @Little Depends - for vectors operator[] is usually shorter, clearer, and might even be a tiny bit faster.

Comment: It might be slower as well. For example if the runtime performs bounds checking like MSVC does by default in some versions.

Answer (score 3):

You should change v++ to i++

Answer (score 2):

v++ is the reason